# Convert string of list of list to normal python list

Tags: python, string, list

I have a string in the format of

```
string= "['a', 'b', 'a e']['de']['a']['a']"
```

I want this string to get converted into a list of list as

```
lst= [['a', 'b', 'a e'], ['de'], ['a'], ['a']]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import ast

string = "['a', 'b', 'a e']['de']['a']['a']"
string = string.replace("]", "],")
list_ = list(ast.literal_eval(string))
print(list_)
```

output:

```
[['a', 'b', 'a e'], ['de'], ['a'], ['a']]
```

Keep in mind that this will fail if one of items in the list is a `]` character.

Comment: Thank you. This worked. I found out the mistake I was doing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way  -

```
import ast

string = "['a', 'b', 'a e']['de']['a']['a']"

[ast.literal_eval(i+']') for i in string.split(']') if len(i)>0]
```

```
[['a', 'b', 'a e'], ['de'], ['a'], ['a']]
```

**Explanation:**

1. `string.split(']')` breaks the list by the `]` bracket
2. `i+']'` appends the `]` bracket which is now removed back for each element
3. `len(i)>0` makes sure that no empty lists are being considered
4. `ast.literal_eval(i+']')` converts the string to actual list.